# How to get the very next element from the list after finding the key element

Tags: c#, linq

Scenario: I have a student list which comprise of name(distinct) and mark. Once user enters the name, I have to display the appropriate mark in console application. How to get the next element after fine the name.

Example:
// User enters like follows:

```
rice 
50
john
60
pat
70
```

// If user enter "john" then--
60 // should display

Using LINQ I have found the key element in the list

```
var item = students.Find(x => x.Name == keyname);
```

Comment: `var item = students.Where(x => x.Name == keyname).Select(x=>x.Whatever);`

Comment: You should really be formatting the input into a structure. i.e. Enter a name, enter a number, then you create and initialise a class object that has a Name and Age component

Comment: I would use a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a class:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Mark {get;set;}
}
```

And you have a list that looks like:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>
{
    new Student{Name = "Markus", Mark = 2},
    new Student{Name = "Stephen", Mark = 1}
};
```

And you want to get the mark of Stephen its:

```
Student stephen = students.FirstOrDefault(s=> s.Name == "Stephen"); //if you have an unique property i you can use .SingleOrDefault in the same manner
if(stephen != null) //could be that the student is not even in the list
{
     int markofStephen = stephen.Mark;
}
```

now to enter in this new DataType you can do:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
do
{
     Console.Write("Please enter the Name of the Student(enter \"finish\" to  exit):");
     string name = Console.ReadLine();
     if(name.ToLower() == "finish" )
         break;
     bool validMark = false;
     do
     {
         Console.Write("Please enter the Mark of {0}:", name);
         string markString = Console.ReadLine();
         int mark;
         validMark = int.TryParse(markString,out mark);
         if(!validMark)
             Console.WriteLine("Invalid Number Entered");
         else
             students.Add(new Student{Name=name, Mark = mark});
     } while (!validMark)
 } while (true)
```

Comment: It helps me to fix the issue. I have altered a bit. private static void DisplayStudentMark()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter name of student");
            string temp = Console.ReadLine(); 
            Student stud = students.Where(s => s.Name == temp).FirstOrDefault(); 

            if (stud != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Marks for" + temp + "is: {0} ".PadLeft(10), stud.Mark);
            }
            else
            {                
                Console.WriteLine("Student: '{0}' does not exist ", temp);                
            } 
        }

Comment: @Pat FirstOrDefault has an overload that takes a predicate so you can simplify the statement like i did. No need to call .Where() before

Answer (score 1):

Do the below code:

`var itemIndex = students.IndexOf(keyname);`

And then the index of the value will be `var value = students.ElementAt(itemIndex+1);`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at OOP
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep

Then you can create a Class or Struct that would define rice and 50.

i.e

```
public class Student
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public double Mark {get;set;}
}
```

Then via Console you can construct a new Student and then store it in a list

```
var item = students.Where(x => x.Name == keyname).Select(x=>x.Mark).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(item);
//or
var item = students.Where(x => x.Name == keyname).FirstOrDefault();
if (item != null)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Mark);
//or
var item = students.FirstOrDefault(s=> s.Name == keyname);
if (item != null)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Mark);
```

Using classes or structures you can achieve better control that storing all values in a list or array

Comment: I have done the same as you mentioned(Using class). Thanks for the suggestion. I have solved the issue which is similar to the first option.

Answer (score 0):

You keep scores and names in the same list so I assume both are strings. In my implementation I take the list of names and scores, take each 2 items, create a tuple, and on a list of tuples I search for one where first item matches your key and return the second item (the score):

```
List<string> testList = new List<string> { "rice", "50", "john", "60", "pat", "70" };
string myKey = "rice";

var result =
    testList.Zip(testList.Skip(1), (a, b) => Tuple.Create(a, b))
            .Where(t => t.Item1 == myKey)
            .First()
            .Item2;
```

Or you can use anonymous types instead of a tuple:

```
var result =
    testList.Zip(testList.Skip(1), (a, b) => new {Name = a, Score = b})
            .Where(t => t.Name == myKey)
            .First()
            .Score;
```

Of course, the assumption is that each name always has a matching score next to it (as that was the condition described in your question).

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var item = students.SkipWhile(x => x.Name != keyname).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```